# 80s or 90s TV episode where a man trapped between two seconds sees world deconstructed and rebuilt

Tags: story-identification, time-travel, tv

I'm trying to find an episode from what I think is a sci-fi TV series produced sometime in the 80s or 90s.

In the episode, a man and another character(s) finds himself stuck in the interval between two seconds.  In that interval, he witnesses a crew of workers whose job it is to destroy the "old" second (everything in it; house, yard, the rest of the world) and build a near duplicate of the upcoming second.

The man is discovered by this "time construction crew" and is told that since he's seen the truth about this in-between time world, he can never return to his time.  He will simply disappear.

He manages to hide at the last minute and the time crew has run out of time to catch him.  The "real" world catches up as the next "second" ticks into place.

I thought this might have been an *Amazing Stories* episode but upon reviewing summaries of those two seasons, I don't think I saw it there.

Does anyone know this episode and series? There were other good episodes in this *Twilight Zone*-like series.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You may be thinking of "[A Matter of Minutes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Matter_of_Minutes)" from *The Twilight Zone*.

> The Wrights, a young married couple, wake up one day to the sounds of construction. When they investigate they find time has stopped. Meanwhile, a crew of blue-clad construction workers are busy removing the furniture in their house and replacing it with new. In terror, the Wrights run outside to find things being rebuilt all over the neighborhood - things that have already existed. The Wrights start to go in the direction of a voice which seems to be commanding the workers, but then turn once the voice commands the workers to capture the Wrights.
>
> Confused and frightened, the couple run into a back alley and enter a void of white space. They discover a man in yellow who helps them out of the void and explains to them that he is the supervisor of the maintenance of time. They have somehow slipped into a loophole and while they should be in an earlier time - 9:33 a.m. - for some reason they have hopped over into 11:37 a.m. Showing them exactly how time is maintained, he reveals to them a new understanding of how the universe works: every minute is essentially a separate world which must be built, maintained, and torn down once it is over. The supervisor informs them that they cannot return for two reasons: 1) they cannot reveal to anyone the true nature of time and 2) the supervisor isn't even certain they could return if they wanted to. The Wrights flee from the foreman and his crew, and try to find a way to slip back to their own time. They hide inside a theater ticket booth and wait until 11:37 a.m. rolls around so they can catch up. The foreman finds them too late as the Wrights suddenly emerge into their own world again. Back in their own time, they find a blue wrench sitting on a public telephone which convinces them they had not dreamed their experience.

It's based on Theodore Sturgeon's "Yesterday was Monday".

Comment: That's exactly it! Thank you! It's been on my mind and no one remembers this.  I'll have to look at the Twilight Zone reboot - there were a few good ones including this one

Comment: The story is a riot too, worth (re-)reading.

Comment: Reminds me of [The Langoliers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Langoliers_(miniseries)), except that is just the past being destroyed after the present is done with it.